# Running Swift build in Terminal leading to "Platform Path" errors

Tags: swift, xcode

I recently reformatted my Mac. Today I tried building a swift executable via Terminal to start a server-side swift project. Here are the commands I've used:

1. **swift package init --type executable**
2. **swift build**

Upon running `swift build`, I got the following errors:

```
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'PlatformPath' from command line tools installation
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'PlatformPath' in SDK '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
```

I'm running **Xcode 8.3.1**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Try fixing the SDK path (yours appears incorrect):

```
$ xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx
```

You might have this result:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

Switch the default SDK location by invoking:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

If that doesn't work then take a look inside the (normal) SDK path:

```
$ ls -lat /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

You should see the SDK's within that directory; if not you'll need to download them.

Comment: for the search engines: this fixed my issue with a kotlin mpp build that was getting stuck with `xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located`

Comment: I strongly suspect this (which happens on all my macs) is due to homebrew installation, which I just noticed is installing the command-line tools even if Xcode is already installed.

Comment: @DaveAbrahams It can happen for various reasons, although that doesn't sound good. I personally use MacPorts, which I find much less invasive than homebrew.

Comment: @DaveAbrahams I can confirm that. I just went through a similar issue and my environment was setup exactly the same. I had just installed homebrew and I noticed it was installing CLI tools.

Comment: Somebody (else) should report this as a bug to Homebrew.  I've used up my goodwill over there ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked for me. And I agree with @DaveAbrahams. The same thing just happened to me because of HOMEBREW INSTALLATION. After installing it I started to run into many problems when running tasks like `swift build`. It seems that Homebrew installs CommandLineTools in this path `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` (which includes the macOSX.sdk) when we are supposed to have all those stuff in the default `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

Answer (score 3):

Select a version of Xcode which can run the `swift build` command by running, for instance:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-8.3.3.app
```

Where Xcode-8.3.3 is the name of your Xcode application